# SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python, syntax

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state= FSMAdmin.photo)ы
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
async while state.proxy() as data:
data['photo'] = messaege.photo[0].file_id
await FSMAdmin.next()
await message.reply("Теперь введите название")
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Новая папка\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,

File "C:\Новая папка\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "c:\Users\pmkut\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in
cli.main()

File "c:\Users\pmkut\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
run()

File "c:\Users\pmkut\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")

File "c:\Users\pmkut\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 320, in run_path
code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)

File "c:\Users\pmkut\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.20.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 294, in _get_code_from_file
code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')

File "c:\BT\pizza_at_home\HANDLERS\admin.py", line 24

async while state.proxy() as data:
^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: Ожидается `async with`

Comment: В `python` важен правильный синтаксис. Вы его соблюдаете? Судя по куску кода вообще никаких отступов нет.